# Nodejs and php in same environment in aws Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a application where I have both nodejs and php codes. nodejs is used to run several scripts required by the application. How do i deploy such application using aws Elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish

Amazon Beanstalk recommended way#1:

- Use Configuration File to install nodejs. Configuration File scripts
  will be executed during Beanstalk EC2 instances start up.

Legacy way#2:

- Customizing an Elastic Beanstalk AMI to install nodejs and fill your
  Custom AMI ID in Beanstalk Environment Setting.

References:

1.[Customizing and Configuring AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)

2.[Using Custom AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)