# Amazon Elastic beanstalk : Use nginx/apache to forward subdomains to subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created my node.js app on ebs with two subrouters 'foo' and 'bar', currently accessible via 'example.com/foo' and 'example.com/bar'.

I'd like the reverse proxy of ebs to forward the subdomains "foo.example.com" and "bar.example.com" to these subfolders...

i.e. "foo.example.com/xxx" to "example.com/foo/xxx" 
"bar.example.com/yyy" to "example.com/bar/yyy" etc.

I know how to configure nginx to do this, but I can't figure out to access the nginx config files on EBS...

Someone asked exactly [the same thing over a year ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/407961/setting-up-subdomains-within-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk), but it seems EBS has developped a good deal since... would just like to know if this sort of thing is now doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use Configuration File to customize your nginx configuration.

1. Create an `.ebextensions` directory in the top-level of your source bundle.
2. Create a configuration file, `/your_app/.ebextensions/custom.config`. Type the following inside the configuration file to configure forward settings. (I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/phstudy/6381331))

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf" :
    content: |
      server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name foo.chief-motp.com;
        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs/foo/;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         }
         location /public {
           alias /var/app/current/public;
         }
      }
      server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name bar.chief-motp.com;
        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs/bar/;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        location /public {
          alias /var/app/current/public;
        }
      }
```

Another methodology to customize Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances is using Custom AMI. For more information, you can refer [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783679/nodejs-and-php-in-same-environment-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk/18499705#18499705).