# Installing Nexus Repo Manager on ElasticbeanStalk

Tags: nexus, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to install Sonatype Nexus on a Micro Instance of Elasticbean Stalk instance ? Can anyone point me to how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can user beanstalk docker stack and attach volume dynamically to it.

Dockerrun.aws.json :

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "sonatype/nexus3:3.21.1",
      "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": "8081"
      },
      {
        "ContainerPort": 8082,
        "HostPort": 8082
      },
      {
        "ContainerPort": 8083,
        "HostPort": 8083
      }        

    ],
    "Volumes": [
      {
        "HostDirectory": "/media/ebs_volume/nexus-data",
        "ContainerDirectory": "/nexus-data"
      }
    ]
  }
```

.ebextensions/00_volume.config :

```
commands:
  01-attach-volume:
    command: aws ec2 attach-volume --region eu-west-1 --volume-id vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxx --instance-id $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --device /dev/sdh
    ignoreErrors: true
  02-wait:
    command: sleep 30
  03-attach-volume:
    command: |
      aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --region eu-west-1 --instance-id $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"/dev/sdh\",\"Ebs\":{\"DeleteOnTermination\":false}}]"
    ignoreErrors: true
  04-mount-volume:
    command: |
      mkdir -p /media/ebs_volume
      mount /dev/sdh /media/ebs_volume
      service docker restart
    test: sh -c "! grep -qs '/media/ebs_volume' /proc/mounts"
  05-create-data-folder:
    command: |
      mkdir -p /media/ebs_volume/nexus-data && chown -R 200:200 /media/ebs_volume/nexus-data  
    ignoreErrors: true
```

And you may need to tune nginx configuration ( for uploads )

.ebextensions/01_nginx_custom.config :

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    group: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 512M;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype Nexus can't deploy in a servlet container or alternative application server [[1](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21186046.html?__utma=246996102.619038740.1381420271.1381420271.1381573096.2&__utmb=246996102.2.10.1381573096&__utmc=246996102&__utmx=-&__utmz=246996102.1381573096.2.2.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=75123985)].

So you must replace the default tomcat server with Sonatype Nexus application server. I think you can try to use [custom elastic beanstalk AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783679/nodejs-and-php-in-same-environment-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk/18499705#18499705) to accomplish it.